# Write Reserved Keywords into a file in Windows batch file

Tags: sql, windows, batch-file

I am working on generating script files from SQL Server 2005 and writing them to a file using Master.dbo.xp_cmdshell command. Due to security reasons, it has been disabled.

So I printed the commands to the console window and pasted it to a scriptfile.bat file and executed it.

Now I'm facing a new issue. When the batch file encounters this line, it exits.

```
echo If @intA <> @intB > "C:\output_file.txt"
```

My question is, how can I write code samples from other programming languages (SQL) to a file in command prompt? The line `If @intA <> @intB` is a string and it needs to be dumped into the file.

Let me know on how to handle this.

Edited: Removed double quotes from the code.

Comment: You are not really using MS-DOS are you?

Comment: MS-DOS is a long retired operating system. My question is, if you are really using **that** or if you are simply referring to the commandline (and batch files) in Windows

Comment: Oh sorry. I meant the command prompt in windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try escaping reserved characters with a caret:

```
echo.If @intA ^<^> @intB> "C:\output_file.txt"
```

Comment: Thanks it worked. In this case, can I escape all reserved characters with a caret ^ ?

Comment: @Bharath Kumar: Alas, I am not sure. I can only think that with the internal echo command it is okay.

Answer (score 0):

Change this line

```
echo If @intA <> @intB > "C:\output_file.txt"
```

To

```
echo "If @intA <> @intB" > "C:\output_file.txt"
```

As the symbol `<` and `>` need to be escaped from shell.

Comment: Yes I tried the code. But double quotes are also written to the file as
`"If @intA <> @intB"`